# Solidity convert HEX number to HEX string

Tags: bit-manipulation, solidity, rsk

I need to store a value of this kind `0xff0000` or `0x00ff08` (hex colour representation) in solidity smart contract and be able to convert it inside a contract to a string with the same text characters `"ff0000"`. I intend to deploy this smart contract on RSK.

My idea was to store those values in a `bytes3` or simply `uint` variable and to have a pure function converting `bytes3` or `uint` to corresponding string. I found a function that does the job and working on solidity 0.4.9

```
pragma solidity 0.4.9;

contract UintToString {
    function uint2hexstr(uint i) public constant returns (string) {
        if (i == 0) return "0";
        uint j = i;
        uint length;
        while (j != 0) {
            length++;
            j = j >> 4;
        }
        uint mask = 15;
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
        uint k = length - 1;
        while (i != 0){
            uint curr = (i & mask);
            bstr[k--] = curr > 9 ? byte(55 + curr ) : byte(48 + curr); // 55 = 65 - 10
            i = i >> 4;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
}
```

But I need a more recent compiler version (at least 0.8.0). The above function is not working on newer versions.

What's the way to convert `bytes` or `uint` to a hex string (1->'1',f->'f') what works in Solidity >=0.8.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following compiles, and was tested using solc 0.8.7
It is the same as your original version, with the following modifications:

- `constant` --> `pure`
- `returns (string)` --> `returns (string memory)`
- `byte(...)` -->  `bytes1(uint8(...))`

The above changes overcame all of the compile-time differences in your original function.
... however there was still a run-time error that was causing this function to revert:

While debugging, the line `bstr[k--] = curr > 9 ?` triggered the revert in the last iteration of the loop it was in. This was because the while loop was set up such that `k` was `0` in its final iteration.

While the identification was tricky, the fix was simple: Change the decrement operator from postfixed to prefixed - `bstr[--k] = curr > 9 ?`.

> Aside:
>
> Q: Why did this not revert when compiled in solc 0.4.9,
> but revert when the same code was compiled in solc 0.8.7?
>
> A: solc 0.8.0 introduced a breaking change where uint overflow and underflow checks were inserted by the compiler.
> Prior to this one would have needed to use `SafeMath` or similar to accomplish the same.
> [See the "Silent Changes of the Semantics" section of the solc 0.8 release notes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html#silent-changes-of-the-semantics)

```
pragma solidity >=0.8;

contract TypeConversion {
    function uint2hexstr(uint i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        if (i == 0) return "0";
        uint j = i;
        uint length;
        while (j != 0) {
            length++;
            j = j >> 4;
        }
        uint mask = 15;
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
        uint k = length;
        while (i != 0) {
            uint curr = (i & mask);
            bstr[--k] = curr > 9 ?
                bytes1(uint8(55 + curr)) :
                bytes1(uint8(48 + curr)); // 55 = 65 - 10
            i = i >> 4;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
}
```