# How to convert bytes3 to HEX string in Solidity

Tags: bit-manipulation, solidity, rsk

I previously asked about [converting uint to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69301408/solidity-convert-hex-number-to-hex-string). Now I want to store a HEX value `0x00ff08` in a `bytes3` variable and to be able to convert it to a `string` in Solidity smart contract. Subsequently I intend to deploy it on RSK with Solidity compiler version at least 0.8.0 .

I tried this `string(abi.encodePacked(bytes3(`**`0x00ff08`**`)))` but it throws a runtime error

*Failed to decode output: null: invalid codepoint at offset 1; bad codepoint prefix (argument="bytes", value={"0":0,"1":255,"2":8}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=strings/5.4.0)*

A different argument `string(abi.encodePacked(bytes3(`**`0x443322`**`)))` doesn't cause an error, but returns a very strange `D3"` result. What could be the problem here? How do I convert `bytes3` to a `string` with the same characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason for the behaviour you've observed**

`abi.encodePacked(myBytes3)` produces 3 bytes because every 2 hexadecimal characters results in 1 bytes. so when you wrap that in `string(..)` you do get a string with 1 character per 1 byte, which in this case, results in a string with 3 characters. For some inputs this results in a string that *can* be rendered as a human readable string. In other cases, it results in a string that cannot be, hence the parse error.

**Solution**

You cannot use `abi.encodePacked(..)` in this case, because "packing" is the *opposite* of what you're trying to accomplish - to render a `bytes3` as a hexadecimal `string` - one that is human readable, ASCII encoded - you would need to do something similar to
[my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69302348/194982), where you use a combination of bit shifting with bit masking to extract one character per half byte.

**Code**

Utility function that converts a single `uint8` into the ASCII character that would represent it in hexadecimal:

```
    function uint8tohexchar(uint8 i) public pure returns (uint8) {
        return (i > 9) ?
            (i + 87) : // ascii a-f
            (i + 48); // ascii 0-9
    }
```

Function that converts a `uint24` to a 6 character hexadecimal `string`.

Note that since this time you're not looking for a "general purpose" solution, but rather one that is specific to `bytes3`, there is no need for any loops, but rather, a sequential set of statements will do. Probably nets some gas savings too .(to be confirmed!)

```
    function uint24tohexstr(uint24 i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory o = new bytes(6);
        uint24 mask = 0x00000f;
        o[5] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[4] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[3] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[2] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[1] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[0] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        return string(o);
    }
```

And finally, you probably want a function that explicitly accepts `bytes3` as a parameter.

Note that this is purely for convenience, as all it really does is a type cast. The `bytes3` and `uint24` can be thought of simply as "24 bits" being viewed/ interpreted in different ways.

```
    function bytes3tohexstr(bytes3 i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        uint24 n = uint24(i);
        return uint24tohexstr(n);
    }
```