# Convert uint24 to HEX string in Solidity

Tags: bit-manipulation, solidity, rsk

I am trying to convert uint24 value of a kind `0x00ff08` to a human readable `string` with the same characters in Solidity smart contract which I am going to deploy on RSK. In my question about [bytes3 to hex string casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312285/how-to-convert-bytes3-to-hex-string-in-solidity) I was advised for these purposes to use a function

```
function uint24tohexstr(uint24 i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory o = new bytes(6);
        uint24 mask = 0x00000f;
        o[5] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[4] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[3] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[2] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[1] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        i = i >> 4;
        o[0] = bytes1(uint8tohexchar(uint8(i & mask)));
        return string(o);
    }
```

I wanted to make use of a loop in that function and rewrote it like this

```
function uint24ToHexStr(uint24 i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory o = new bytes(6);
        uint24 mask = 0x00000f; // hex 15
        for(uint k = 5; k >= 0; k -= 1) {
          o[k] = bytes1(uint8ToHexCharCode(uint8(i & mask)));
          i >>= 4;
        }
        return string(o);
    }
```

But unfortunately this function causes runtime error because on the last iteration unsigned integer `k` becomes `-1`. The first thing that crossed my mind was to increase k by one so that

```
        for(uint k = 6; k >= 1; k -= 1) {
          o[k - 1] = bytes1(uint8ToHexCharCode(uint8(i & mask)));
        }
```

Can anyone think of a more elegant way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the 2nd option in [@selbie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328880/194982); and thought what if we used a different type of loop control structure. A regular `while` loop would inherit the same "final iteration `uint` underflow" problem that the `for` loop has. Switching to a `do .. while` loop, on the other hand, allows you to shift the evaluation of the condition from being checked *before* the iteration, to being checked *after* the iteration. This can be applied to your implementation like so:

```
    function uint24ToHexStr(uint24 i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory o = new bytes(6);
        uint24 mask = 0x00000f; // hex 15
        uint k = 6;
        do {
            k--;
            o[k] = bytes1(uint8ToHexCharCode(uint8(i & mask)));
            i >>= 4;
        } while (k > 0);
        return string(o);
    }
```

This avoids both the `uint` underflow, and also does not require `k - 1` for array indices within the loop. In terms of gas cost, I would "guesstimate" that it would be close to the original implementation of the same function from the previous question. (but actually try both out and compare to confirm)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
for(uint k = 5; k >= 0; k -= 1) {
```

If `k` is of type `uint`, when will `k >= 0` ever evaluate to false? (hint: never)

Change `k` from type `uint` to `int` and problem is solved.

```
    for(int k = 5; k >= 0; k -= 1) {
      o[k] = bytes1(uint8ToHexCharCode(uint8(i & mask)));
      i >>= 4;
    }
```

Or

```
    for(uint k = 0; k< 6; k += 1) {
      o[5-k] = bytes1(uint8ToHexCharCode(uint8(i & mask)));
      i >>= 4;
    }
```

Comment: Right, never evaluate to false, but on the last iteration of the loop k becomes -1 that is impossible for uints and causes an error! I am using uints because It seems to me that in the glorious Solidity language array indices are uints :)  But your second idea is nice, thanks !

Comment: Oooh, I like the 2nd option! Neat way to use `for` loops while sticking to `uint` for the counter var!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer, also taking some inspiration [from @selbie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328880/194982) of forward iteration, but instead of reversing the index order,
get the target half-byte by *switching* from a bitwise-and mask
to a bit-shift of 5 half-bytes (20 bits).
Like so:

```
   function uint24ToHexStrAlt2(uint24 i) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory o = new bytes(6);
        uint k = 0;
        do {
            o[k] = bytes1(uint8ToHexCharCode(uint8(i >> 20))); // shift by 5 nibbles instead of mask
            i <<= 4;
            k +=1;
        } while (k < 6);
        return string(o);
    }
```